# Trying to only show header when accordion menu is not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, toggleclass

I have been at this problem for days now, and I know it is a simple fix but I just can't get it!

Right now, the header to my site is displayed, but once an accordion item is clicked the header is hidden, but I am trying to make it that if none of the accordion items are active, display the header again.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    $('.heading').hide(); 
    var active = document.querySelector(".accordion.active");
    if (active && active != this) {
      active.classList.remove("active");
      active.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    } 
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  } 

};
```

I just need to make the heading display when nothing is active! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that accodion is opening one tab at a time. which means when you click on one active one, it close all set. If this is true, we can simply check when active element is clicked and in that case show the "heading"

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    $('.heading').hide(); 
    var active = document.querySelector(".accordion.active");
if (active && active == this) {
      $('.heading').show(); 
    }     
if (active && active != this) {
      active.classList.remove("active");
      active.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    } 
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  } 

};
```

Comment: <div class="accordionWrapper">
 <button class="accordion">Where?</button>
 <div class="panel">
   <section class="where">
   </section>
 </div>

 <button class="accordion">When?</button>
 <div id="foo" class="panel">
   <section>

    <div class="content">
       </div>
   </section>
 </div>

 <button class="accordion">Beans?</button>
 <div class="panel">
   <section>
      </section>

 </div>

That is just the HTML gutted of the content! Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: for some reason that leads to a console error, Invalid left alignment? I don't know, I have never seen that one before.

Comment: editing my answer and comparing with ==. Please use jsfiddle.net in future  questions. that will make life easier

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you declare a `var count` global variable. Everytime you activate a section increase `count` by 1, i.e `count++` , and everytime you deactivate - `count--`.

Now if `count <= 0` at any point - show the header again.

Comment: That is a very good idea! Would you say something like this is going on the right track?
    document.getElementsByClassName('accordion').onclick = function (e) {
           count++;
           if (e.preventDefault) {
               e.preventDefault();
           }
           e.returnValue = false;
       };

I'm a little confused by it